# RDP can't reconnect after connection drops

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

We have a number of development VMs running which we typically access through RDP. After a few hours the connection will drop leaving us unable to reconnect giving the following message:

> This computer can't connect to the remote computer.
>
> Try connecting again. If the problem continues, contact the owner of
>   the remote computer or your network administrator.

It looks like the server side is left in a state of limbo preventing it from accepting any new connections.

The only reliable way I'm aware of to fix the issue without rebooting the VM itself is to simply log on using the VSphere console. Once logged in we don't need to do anything except close the console window.

Simply logging in this way seems to release the connection and the RDP begins working again. So while this works, it's really annoying.

This issue began when our company started using IPv6. I can still successfully ping the VM when it is in this state. The VM is running Windows 2k8, my machine is Windows 7.

I've been digging around for a while and found similar issues but none that seem to address what we are seeing.

My question is, has anyone seen this issue before? And is there a better solution to release what I'm guessing are stale sessions?

Comment: Some reports say that such problems are caused by (1) network printer being off, (2) the Windows feature "Windows Location Provider" - to be uninstalled, (3) antivirus software, (4) UDP protocol - to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue where systems had been P2Vd. A physical system will WOL when you bump the NIC, but a VM doesn't. Check your power settings and make sure Windows never sleeps, HDD always on, etc.